# Facebook API: Only displaying videos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to scrape data from old Facebook posts from the New York Times for a research project, using the Facebook API. For recent dates this works fine, and I've been able to collect all the information I need. However, starting in around January the API begins to only provide me with their video posts.

**The question then: How do I ensure that I see all of the posts**, particularly given I don't really need the videos, at all. I am exclusively interested in the links.

For reference, this is what I'd like to see:

[image: Desired]

This is what I actually see:

[image: Actual]

and the address I use to generate these from the graph explorer: `5281959998/posts/?fields=type,created_time,link&limit=100&until=2017-01-15`

Comment: I still see all kinds of types when I click the next link in Graph API Explorer a couple of times, with dates in mid January …

Comment: @CBroe: That is likely because I sent you to February (2017-02-15) instead of January. I have corrected that in the post. Specifically, the last time a post with the type link appears is January 12, at 5:55 GMT.